# overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: inherit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div (id="c_content)` which I want to expand vertically depending on how long the content is without displaying the contents which overflow horizontally.
I am using the following code at the moment and it doesn't seem to work:-

```
#c_content {
        min-height: 645px;
        max-height: 2000px;
    overflow-y: inherit; overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When I use the above code, the content which overflows vertically is hidden. What should happen is, the div should expand vertically in order to show the content. But that doesn't seem to happen.
edit: when I set `overflow-y: visible;` instead of `overflow-y: inherit;`, I get a scroll bar for y axis (http://prntscr.com/108wsm) - still not what I wanted.

I would like to know if there is any way to fix this even if I have to user another code like `Java` or `Jquery`

Comment: Are you implementing any jQuery code, if you are, can you please post it in an edit?

Comment: Yes I am implementing any Java or jQuery

Comment: Try setting up a JSFiddle that replicates your problem -- that way we could experiment

Answer (score 1):

Use cross browser min-height trick .. It will expand div when necessary.

```
#c_content { 
   min-height: 645px; 
   height:auto !important; 
   height: 645px;
   max-height:2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`inherit` is not a valid value for the `overflow-y` property. Try setting it to `overflow-y:visible;`